# Add Interval to date in HSQLDB based on other column

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I'm using hsqldb as in-memory database for unittests, the production system is running with mysql. The following query does work with mysql, but not if applied with hsqldb:

```
select * from table where columnTimestamp + INTERVAL 'columnDays' DAY < now();
```

I want to retrieve all specific rows where the interval is based on another column. When I use fixed values it does work with hsqldb, but this is not the required behaviour.

The errormessage hsqldb returns:

```
data exception: invalid interval format / Error Code: -3406 / State: 22006
```

Answer (score 3):

Multiply a constant interval with your column.

```
select * 
from table 
where columnTimestamp + (INTERVAL '1' DAY * columndays) < now();
```

Comment: Nice idea, but it doesn' seems that this syntax is valid in mysql neither in hsqlb.

Comment: @Dag: Works for me (when using a different table name than `table`) with HSQLDB 2.3, which version are you using?

Comment: hsqldb 2.3.2, MySQL 5.6.x in MySQL: `...for the right syntax to use near ') * intervalDays < now()' at line 3, SQLState:  42000, ErrorCode: 1064`. In hsqldb I get `unexpected token: )`

Comment: That is a MySQL error message you asked for a query for HSQLDB. In HSQLDB you could try to put the `)` differently (see my edit). But that doesn't make any difference for me using HSQLDB 2.3.2.

Comment: In the question I describe that the query is only executed on hsqldb for testing purposes, so it must run on mysql likewise. Moving `)` didn't helped, tried that already, sorry. I'm running hsql in-memory and using the `DatabaseManagerSwing` client.

Comment: @Dag: another good example why using a different DBMS for testing and production is not a good idea. I have no idea though why it doesn't work for you with HSQLDB.