# Unexpected token in date_add function for hsqldb when using column name as inteval expr

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, hsqldb

This query works against a MySQL DB.

```
update MYTABLE set my_date = date_add(:currentDate, INTERVAL num_days_column DAY);
```

Where num_days_column is an integer column

This works in MySQL. However, when I try to run the same query in HSQLDB, the query fails with the following error:
Unexpected token : num_days_column.

Would appreciate any ideas on how I could solve this.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to [Add Interval to date in HSQLDB based on other column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650406/add-interval-to-date-in-hsqldb-based-on-other-column?rq=1)
Resolving question since this is a duplicate of that question.